# statement is incomplete when calling procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a code to make a procedure in my database but when I try to call it, it never accepts the statement.

I'm new to mysql and I can't figure out whats wrong when I tried everything, putting the semi colon, retyping everything etc.

Heres my code i want to implement:

```
 DELIMITER // 
 CREATE PROCEDURE PriceChange(thisCodeFromBook CHAR(4), thisFormat 
 CHAR(1), thisGivenPrice DECIMAL (4,2))
 BEGIN
 UPDATE BOOK
 SET  PRICE = thisGivenPrice
 WHERE  BOOK_CODE = thisCodeFromBook AND PAPERBACK = thisFormat;
 END //
```

but when i want to call the procedure it never finishes:

```
call PROCEDURE PriceChange('0180','Y','7.15');
```

Here is the result i get:

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE PriceChange(thisCodeFromBook CHAR(4), thisFormat 
CHAR(1), thisGivenPrice DECIMAL (4,2))
 -> BEGIN
 -> UPDATE BOOK
 -> SET  PRICE = thisGivenPrice
 -> WHERE  BOOK_CODE = thisCodeFromBook AND PAPERBACK = thisFormat;
 -> END //
mysql> CALL PriceChange('0180','Y','7.15');
 ->
 ->
 ->
```

Comment: It should be just `CALL PriceChange('0180','Y','7.15');`

Answer (score 3):

You didn't set your DELIMITER back to `;`

Comment: I guess 384k makes you 18 times faster than me ;-)

Comment: If i put delimiter; after the end// it doesn't accept the statement still

Comment: @heyley you need `DELIMITER ;` with a space before `;`.